# ¿ Como puedo acceder a los valores de las etiquetas de un XML con jquery?

Tags: jquery

Este es el ejemplo de un documento XML y quiero acceder al valor de la fecha que esta con el nombre de fecDocto ¿ como saco ese valor ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Por ejemplo, para el primer elemento, Fíjate si te puede servir esto:

```
$.get("Documentos.xml", function (xml) {
    $(xml).find("ImgIdentOficialFrontal").each(function () {

       var name = $(this).attr('name');
       var fecDocto= $(this).attr('fecDocto');

       alert("name:" + name + " / fecDocto: " + fecDocto);
    });
});
```